# Convert csv file to dataframe in Spark 1.5.2 without databricks

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a csv file to a dataframe in Spark 1.5.2 with Scala without the use of the library databricks, as it is a community project and this library is not available. My approach was the following:

```
var inputPath  = "input.csv"
var text = sc.textFile(inputPath)
var rows = text.map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim))
var header = rows.first()
var data = rows.filter(_(0) != header(0))
var df = sc.makeRDD(1 to data.count().toInt).map(i => (data.take(i).drop(i-1)(0)(0), data.take(i).drop(i-1)(0)(1), data.take(i).drop(i-1)(0)(2), data.take(i).drop(i-1)(0)(3), data.take(i).drop(i-1)(0)(4))).toDF(header(0), header(1), header(2), header(3), header(4))
```

This code, even though it is quite a mess, works without returning any error messages. The problem comes when trying to display the data inside `df`in order to verify the correctness of this method and later try to do some queries in `df`. The error code I am getting after executing `df.show()` is `SPARK-5063`. My questions are:

**1)** Why is it not possible to print the content of `df`?

**2)** Is there any other more straightforward method to convert a csv to a dataframe in `Spark 1.5.2` without using the library `databricks`?

Comment: _"it is a community project"_ -- are you serious? Do you know that Databricks is **the** company which drives Spark development? Do you know that the `spark-csv` plug-in has been merged into Spark 2.x core libraries?

Comment: The problem is that I do not have the chance to change that, therefore I am looking for alternative ways to parse a csv to a dataframe without using Databricks.

Comment: _"change that"_ -- what do you mean? That you cannot download the JAR (once and for all) and attach it to the job with `--jars`, along with its `commons-csv` dependency? It worked pretty well for me with Spark bundled in the CDH distro (note that with an Apache build, `--jars` did not work well with CDH, I had to go for `spark.driver.extraClasspath` prop and an explicit `sc.addJar()` as a workaround)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For spark 1.5.x can be used code snippet below to convert input into DF

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
// this is used to implicitly convert an RDD to a DataFrame.
import sqlContext.implicits._

// Define the schema using a case class.
// Note: Case classes in Scala 2.10 can support only up to 22 fields. To work around this limit,
// you can use custom classes that implement the DataClass interface with 5 fields.
case class DataClass(id: Int, name: String, surname: String, bdate: String, address: String)

// Create an RDD of DataClass objects and register it as a table.
val peopleData = sc.textFile("input.csv").map(_.split(",")).map(p => DataClass(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1).trim, p(2).trim, p(3).trim, p(4).trim)).toDF()
peopleData.registerTempTable("dataTable")

val peopleDataFrame = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from dataTable")

peopleDataFrame.show()
```

[Spark 1.5](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/sql-programming-guide.html#interoperating-with-rdds)

Answer (score 2):

You can create like this:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("RDDtoDF_Updated")
                .master("local[2]")
                .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
                .getOrCreate();

        StructType schema = DataTypes
                .createStructType(new StructField[] {
                        DataTypes.createStructField("eid", DataTypes.IntegerType, false),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("eName", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("eAge", DataTypes.IntegerType, true),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("eDept", DataTypes.IntegerType, true),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("eSal", DataTypes.IntegerType, true),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("eGen", DataTypes.StringType,true)});


        String filepath = "F:/Hadoop/Data/EMPData.txt";
        JavaRDD<Row> empRDD = spark.read()
                .textFile(filepath)
                .javaRDD()
                .map(line -> line.split("\\,"))
                .map(r -> RowFactory.create(Integer.parseInt(r[0]), r[1].trim(),Integer.parseInt(r[2]),
                        Integer.parseInt(r[3]),Integer.parseInt(r[4]),r[5].trim() ));


        Dataset<Row> empDF = spark.createDataFrame(empRDD, schema);
        empDF.groupBy("edept").max("esal").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Spark with Scala.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

var hiveCtx = new HiveContext(sc)
var inputPath  = "input.csv"
var text = sc.textFile(inputPath)
var rows = text.map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim)).map(a => Row.fromSeq(a))
var header = rows.first()
val schema = StructType(header.map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName.asInstanceOf[String],StringType,true)))

val df = hiveCtx.createDataframe(rows,schema)
```

This should work.

But for creating dataframe, would recommend you to use [Spark-CSV](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv).